# Make an apache alias point to a folder in a trucrypt container

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, truecrypt

I tried making an Alias directory point to a directory in a truecrypt container and I always get a 403 Denied error. Can anyone fix this.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the user Apache is running as doesn't have access to the truecrypt container.

I'm sure this can be fixed using `sudo` and mounting the truecrypt volume as the Apache user, but my gut instinct would be not to do this in the first place.

It opens a potential security hole (as the Apache service gets access to the truecrypt file), and is bound to be much slower than an Alias to an unencrypted location.

Answer (score 0):

I see this question was asked long time ago.
I had the same issue with this so I am writing here the solution I found for this issue.

The solution will be running truecrypt from command line using the option to choose what
user groups and file permissions will be granted to the truecrypt media/disc.
Use the following command (change it according to your needs):

```
sudo truecrypt --fs-options=users,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0000,dmask=0000 --mount /vol.tc /media/truecrypt1
```

I used these permissions because it is a local development machine.